# Correct Rails ActiveRecord model design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to find the best way to setup my models to store color palette data. Here is how I see the setup:

```
class Colour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :palettes
end
```

`Colour` has the following properties:

```
:hex_value:string
:rgb_value:string 
:association_id:integer
:association_type:string
```

A `Palette` object

```
class Palette < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :colours
end
```

`Palette` has the following properties:

```
:name:string
:colours: ?
```

A `Product` object

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :palette

end
```

`Product` has the following properties:

```
:name:string
:palette_id:integer
```

My problem is, for each colour in a palette there is also a percentage value that I need to be able to store. I can't find the solution for how to store this value.
I feel like there is a way that I can create a palette model that has many colours and for each associated colour there is a percentage assigned. I know this is not the correct way to represent it, but i feel like it should be something like

```
:name:string
:colours: array[:color:object, :percentage:decimal]
```

Also, I have designed the `Colour` object to be polymorphic as I want to be able to use this later.

I hope this makes sense, this is by far the most advanced data design i have done to date.

Comment: I guess you're doing this app as an excersise because those are very weird classes to have :D
What you're looking for though are has_many something, through: something_else relationships, they are described very well in Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [`has_many :through` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for your `Colour` and `Palette` models. [Choosing that instead of a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) will allow you to use your join table to store your percentage data.

Comment: So between `Colour` and `Palette` I would have another model called say `ColourMatch` that has an attribute called `:percentage`? And then `Palette` would reference `Colour` like this: `has_many :colours, through :colourmatchs` ?

Comment: `has_many :colours, through: :colourmatches` actually (Rails handles plurals pretty well), but yeah. Also, `Colour` would reference `Palette` with `has_many :palettes, through: :colourmatches`

Comment: Thanks @Jason! This is exactly what I was after!